# How do I give 100% height to an iframe that is inside of a frame in a frameset

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried css

```
iframe {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
         height:100%; 

    }
```

I also tried javascript

```
function resize()
{
    document.getElementById('dashIframe').style.height = top.main.clientHeight + 'px';

}
```

But I can't get the iframe to be 100% height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iframe is taking the height of the parent element. If there is nothing else in the frame making it larger then the height of the body is 0. 100% of 0 is 0.

You have two solutions, either make the body and html of your frame 100% like so.

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or give your iframe absolute positioning, make sure it is not in any other container that has relative or absolute positioning applied. like so..

```
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

On a side note framesets are no longer supported in HTML5. So I would probably try and find an alternate solution to your frameset. You can achieve the same visual effects just using divs.

Comment: what does html mean in body, html{..?

Comment: html refers to the html tag e.g. `<html>` the html tag holds the entire contents of the document including the body. So if you set the `body {...}` to 100% the '<html>` that contains it still has no height so 100% of 0 is still 0. by setting `html {...}` to 100% the root of your document is the size of the window it is in.